# Insert <p> into div Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a website and I've this HTML code like this

```
<p class="thumb-1"></p>
<p class="thumb-2"></p>
<p class="thumb-3"></p>
<p class="thumb-4"></p>
<p class="thumb-5"></p>
<p class="thumb-6"></p>
<p class="thumb-7"></p>
<p class="thumb-8"></p>

<div class="new new-1"></div>
<div class="new new-2"></div>
<div class="new new-3"></div>
<div class="new new-4"></div>
```

So, I want to put `<p>` into divs like this

```
<div class="new new-1">
 <p class="thumb-1"></p>
 <p class="thumb-5"></p>
</div>
<div class="new new-2">
 <p class="thumb-2"></p>
 <p class="thumb-6"></p>
</div>
<div class="new new-3">
 <p class="thumb-3"></p>
 <p class="thumb-7"></p>
</div>
<div class="new new-4">
 <p class="thumb-4"></p>
 <p class="thumb-8"></p>
</div>
```

I try this :

```
$("p").each(function() {
    $('.new').append($this);
});
```

But I don't know how I can switch to `.new-1` then `.new-2` ect. ..

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what is the logic behind these appends, what do you want to reach? the task is not clear, actually.  As the reference you may check [jQuery Manipulation](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) for DOM interactions, I think this will make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be done using the `%` operator like so:

**jQuery:**

```
$('p').each(function(i) {
    $('.new-'+((i%4)+1)).append($(this))
})
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="new new-1">
    <p class="thumb-1">thumb-1</p>
    <p class="thumb-5">thumb-5</p>
</div>
<div class="new new-2">
    <p class="thumb-2">thumb-2</p>
    <p class="thumb-6">thumb-6</p>
</div>
<div class="new new-3">
    <p class="thumb-3">thumb-3</p>
    <p class="thumb-7">thumb-7</p>
</div>
<div class="new new-4">
    <p class="thumb-4">thumb-4</p>
    <p class="thumb-8">thumb-8</p>
</div>
```

See it working in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/g219zjah/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `each()`, `append()` and `eq()`.

```js
var p = $('p[class^="thumb-"]');

$('.new').each(function (i) {
    $(this).append([p.eq(i), p.eq(i + 4)]);
});
```

```css
div {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="thumb-1">thumb-1</p>
<p class="thumb-2">thumb-2</p>
<p class="thumb-3">thumb-3</p>
<p class="thumb-4">thumb-4</p>
<p class="thumb-5">thumb-5</p>
<p class="thumb-6">thumb-6</p>
<p class="thumb-7">thumb-7</p>
<p class="thumb-8">thumb-8</p>

<div class="new new-1"></div>
<div class="new new-2"></div>
<div class="new new-3"></div>
<div class="new new-4"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").each(function(){
        var num = $(this).attr('class').split('-')[1]
        var rem = num % 4;
        if(rem > 0){
          $('.new-'+rem).append($(this)) 
        }
        else{
          $('.new-4').append($(this)) 
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.new{
  border:1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="thumb-1">1</p>
<p class="thumb-2">2</p>
<p class="thumb-3">3</p>
<p class="thumb-4">4</p>
<p class="thumb-5">5</p>
<p class="thumb-6">6</p>
<p class="thumb-7">7</p>
<p class="thumb-8">8</p>

<div class="new new-1"></div>
<div class="new new-2"></div>
<div class="new new-3"></div>
<div class="new new-4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use below jquery

```
$('.thumb-1, .thumb-5').wrapAll('<div class="new new-1"></div>');
```

This will add .thumb-1 and .thumb-5 to new new-1.

and use similarly for other elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.new').each(function(index,elem){
    $(this).append($('p.thumb-'+(index+1)));
  $(this).append($('p.thumb-'+(index+5)));
});

});
```